# 3 year date range starting from particular month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012
I would like a 'WHERE' clause to pick out data over a 3 year period starting at the beginning of the fiscal year (April in this case) and continuing to present date.

Current Data

```
  Row      date
   A       2019-03-01
   B       2018-01-01
   C       2017-06-05
   D       2017-04-02
   E       2015-08-01
```

What I would like

```
  Row      date
   A       2019-03-01
   B       2018-01-01
   C       2017-06-05
   D       2017-04-02
```

This is what I have tried which isn't what I'm after, I can't get it to start from April

```
date between Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -36,  GETDATE())), 0)   AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

**EDIT: As I've not really explained myself well enough**

I'm trying to create a report in Report Builder which would have a matrix similar to below

```
         Fiscal     Fiscal      Fiscal
   Row   2017/18   2018/19    2019/2020
    A      54         45          66
    B      12         54          76
    C      11         34          56
    D      16         98          99
```

At the start of the next fiscal year I would like my matrix to update like this.

```
     Fiscal        Fiscal      Fiscal
   Row   2018/19   2019/20    2020/2021
    A      45         66          3
    B      54         76          5
    C      34         56          2
    D      98         99          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ugly, but it should work and it should be fast.

```
Select DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, DateAdd(Month, -36, DateAdd(Month, 3 - DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate()) % 12, GetDate()))), 0)
```

Comment: thanks, how can I implement this into my where clause?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your requirements.  The most previous April 1st date as of today would be April 1, 2019.  3 years before that would be April 1, 2016.  Is it your intention to get the data between April 1, 2016 and 3 years from that date (up to April 1, 2019)?

Comment: Sorry when I originally tried this it wasn't working, realised it was something in my query messing it up. Fixed it and now this works great, thank you @G Mastros